# Tables involved in storing order information for a certain product in magento

Tags: magento

What are the Tables involved in storing the information of an order.

For example: Customer - product purchased  - etc.

I found the product purchases status etc.(invoice and sales tables) but having hard time in linking it to the customer. Could not find who bought what ? Any suggestions

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table `sales_flat_order` has a field `customer_id` referring to a row in the `customer_entity` table. But remember that some orders are guest orders, and they are not associated to a customer account. In those cases `customer_id` is `null`.

The products (line items) for an order are stored in `sales_flat_order_item`. There's an `order_id` linking it to the order and a `product_id` linking it to the product.